# Ruby do block messes with bootstrap markup

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, erb

This is probably pretty simple but I'm having issues with my erb in ruby interfering with my bootstrap layout. I'm using a partial to render a simple comment form and depending on where I start/end my do block, it totally screws with my bootstrap layout. I was under the impression that the only thing affected is code within <%= %>. Heres what I have currently. I've been moving it around with little success.

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>

 <ul id="comments" class="comments">
    <li class="comment">
        <div class="clearfix">

            <h4 class="pull-left"><%= comment.name %></h4>

            <p class="pull-right"><%= comment.created_at %></p>
        </div>
        <p>


        </p>
    </li>
 </ul>

        </div>
    <% end %>
```

The above is currently pushing my right two columns underneath the comment form. If I surround only this

```
<em><%= comment.content %></em>
```

with my block it works fine. Anything beyond that as I have above screws it up. Any input would be appreciated as I've run into this before. Thanks.

Comment: why is there an extra `</div>` in the code?

Comment: good question. I was pasting a few things to change it. Let me check

Comment: I deleted it. It was a div from my show page from where I pasted the form. It didn't change the problem however

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Thanks to Anthony. Removing the div didn't help initially but it was the source of the problem. I needed to remove the div and THEN move my do block down to only include the affected markup.